# How to fix node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936?

Tags: node.js

I followed a node.js tutorial online and I got this error when I runned the script.

`node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\sem20\Downloads\testing\API\cmusic-api\index.js' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15) at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 { code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [] }`

I installed every package I needed

Here is the index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

const app = express()




app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`))
```

Can somebody help me fix this?
I installed every package I needed

Comment: It says `generate_metadata.js` module is not found. Check if the file is present and module is exported.

Comment: sorry was the wrong command, I edited it.

Comment: Add a folder structure of your app and show how you start the app.

Comment: sorry stupid me, never worked with VS code before it wasn't in the folder *face_palm*